# Importing database from an sFTP server in Windows Azure

Tags: sql, azure, ftp, scheduled-tasks, database-restore

I'm building a website that will surface data from a third party system. The third party will provide a copy of all the data I need as a SQL restore file (*.bak) inside a rar file on their sftp server.  The data changes every day, so my application will need to connect to the sftp site, get the file, unzip it, then restore it into my database server every night.  I'm fairly comfortable scripting this in a standard windows environment, but the customer would prefer the application to be built on the MS Azure cloud, which doesn't seem to support a common solution to the problem.  It's possible we could abandon Azure, but I'd like to know what the best strategy would be for implementing in Azure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you are trying to use Azure PaaS (cloud service and SQL Azure) or IaaS (VMs). If you are using VMs on Windows Azure, there is going to be no difference between Windows Azure and your familiar Windows environment - so yes, you can do this on Windows Azure.

This can't really be done in Azure cloud services and SQL Azure (SQL Azure cannot restore a .bak file). But your application doesn't seem to be the kind that would run as a cloud service anyway.

Stick to doing it on VMs and it will work as you are familiar with.

Comment: Thanks Simon for the rapid response!  It's SQL Azure the customer wants to use, because they believe it will require less ongoing DB administration and maintenance, but since the .bak file is a constraint it sounds like that's not an option.